# Help identifying math symbols: big crosshair and caret

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computer-science

> $$
> \left[\begin{array}{lllll}
> \psi_{i}(0) & \psi_{i}(1) & \psi_{i}(2) & \ldots & \psi_{i}\left(2^{L}-1\right)
> \end{array}\right]^{\top}
> $$
> $I$ also showed in chapter $? ?$ that $\Psi$ was orthogonal; hence $\Psi$ represents orthogonal basis. It was also noted that w was unique. Recall the definition of $\psi_{i}:$
> $$ \psi_{i}(x)=Y\left(\bigoplus_{k=0}^{L-1}(x[k] \wedge i[k])\right) \quad x, i \in \mathcal{B}^{L}$$

Can anyone identify the names of the crosshair and ^ symbols?

90% sure the ^ means bitwise AND from searching wikipedia, but I haven't found the crosshair symbol anywhere else.

Comment: ^ is called *caret*, not *carrot*.

Comment: I was wondering who would draw a little carrot as an operator in a math equation. Perhaps a Bugs Bunny fan.

Comment: caret***  thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I take it that you’re asking about $\land$ and $\bigoplus$ in this displayed line:

$$\psi_i(x)=Y\left(\bigoplus_{k=0}^{L-1}\left(x[k]\land i[k]\right)\right)\qquad x,i\in\mathcal{B}^L$$

Judging from the context, $\mathcal{B}$ is probably $\{0,1\}$, so that $x$ and $i$ are $L$-bit bitstrings. If so, I expect that you’re right about $\land$: $0\land 0=0\land 1=1\land 0=0$, and $1\land 1=1$. $\bigoplus$ is almost certainly non-carrying addition, or if you prefer, exclusive OR: $0\oplus 0=1\oplus 1=0$, $0\oplus 1=1\oplus 0=1$, and $\bigoplus$ is related to $\oplus$ as $\sum$ is related to $+$.